# Finding Sum of amount per weekday per month MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a task to find the total amount of money paid during weekdays vs weekends.
So first I have to separate the weekdays from the weekends then find the toal amount of money paid on each, per month.

The tables I am using have the following structure

Game_users table

```
game_id | user_id |bill_id| created_at          | deleted_at 
1234    | 244     | 456   |2016-10-08 14:47:11  | null
```

Bills Table

```
bill_id | user_id |amount | created_at          | deleted_at 
1234    | 244     | 100 |2016-10-08 14:47:11    | null
```

So, I have to `sum(amount)` and then separate them into weekdays and weekends per month

So group by `month(created_at)`

I need a query to achieve this expected result

```
Month | count(weekdays) | Total Amount Paid
1     |  34             | 500.0
```

Comment: `... SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(date) > 4 THEN payed ELSE 0 END) AS sum_weekend ...`

Comment: You have two created at columns so your question is not clear.

Comment: I want the created_at from the game_users table and the amount from the bills table